# Equivalent of "truss -T" and "truss -U" on Linux?

Tags: linux, signals, debugging, system-calls, truss

Is there an equivalent of what the `-T` and `-U` option of the [`truss`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19082-01/819-2239/truss-1/) Solaris utility does on Linux.

Those are to specify a system call (`-T`) or library function (`-U`) which when called by the traced application would cause it to stop.

Or, said otherwise, I'd want any process started by a traced application to be stopped (as if killed by SIGSTOP) as soon as it makes a given system call or a given shared library function call.

`strace` and `ltrace` on Linux provide with much of the featureset of Solaris `truss`, but they don't seem to be doing that.

For instance:

```
truss -f -T open cmd
```

Would be like `strace -f cmd` except that if the process executing `cmd` or any of its descendants does any `open` system call, it would be stopped immediately (and I can resume it later on at my convenience)

In some cases, I could use `gdb`'s `catch syscall`, but I was looking for a solution that can conveniently follow forks and continue doing it for all the forked processes and keep on doing it even after `execve`s.

I seem to recall some utility giving the same functionality, even one (or options to that same utility) to single-step applications between some occurrences of some syscall remotely like that, but my memory is failing me, I can't even be sure that was on Linux.

Comment: Not really an answer to your question but gdb does have some options for following forks, it just doesn't key off an execve. It still only does one process at a time, though, which is probably a deal breaker if you're looking for strace-like functionality, but I thought I'd mention it just in case.

Comment: @JoelDavis, thanks. And it seems it can also follow after exec, (`follow-exec-mode`), I'm experimenting with that. Doesn't strictly answer the question, but may be good enough for what I need.

Comment: If I understand your question you're looking for a way to trace until a specific signal is seen and then stop tracing, not halt or kill the application you're tracing in any way, right?

Comment: @slm, no, I want a process started by a traced application to be stopped (as if killed by SIGSTOP) as soon as it makes a given system call. I've added a link to the Solaris `truss` manpage.

Comment: Let me make sure I understand correctly. You want a way to stop a process when it makes a specific systemcall. Is that correct?

Answer (score 3):

To the best of my knowledge this can't be done with `strace`, the `ptrace` function which is used internally does `SIGSTOP` or `SIGINT` on calls.

#### EDIT:

I inserted this simple solution in [ministrace](https://github.com/webhat/ministrace), so no coding is required.

My proposed solution, if the not all the functionality of strace is required, would be to modify ministrace - which I found here [Write yourself an strace in 70 lines of code](http://blog.nelhage.com/2010/08/write-yourself-an-strace-in-70-lines-of-code/).

In a one shot program you could add two lines before the following code:

```
if (wait_for_syscall(child) != 0) break;
```

#### Pseudo code:

```
if(syscall == SYS_write)
    do {
        char str[4];
        gets(str);  // waits until enter to continue    
    } while(0);
```

I've not tesed any of this, these final steps are left to you.

Comment: Thanks. It works and that link is very useful. However (understandably in a few lines of code), it doesn't do the arg decoding that gdb/strace do, so would not have been useful for my purpose. It shows though that it's easily done. I went for gdb in the end but it looks like patching strace for that feature would be relatively easy. Leaving the question open as I suspect there is an existing command to do that. I'll look at python-ptrace when I've got the time.

Comment: You're welcome! I went a little wild in extending the implementation, so it would be possible to reference the syscall by id and by name. It was fun playing with ptrace again.

Answer (score 2):

Systemtap should be able to do what you are looking for, that's a nice guide for it:

https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/SystemTap_Beginners_Guide/